# Adjust IF and OFFSET function to force result to 0

Tags: excel

How can I modify the two formulas below to force the result to be 0 if the  subtraction of N2-N3 for example is a negative number.

First formula is:

```
=IF(E2="New";OFFSET(H2;-1;0)-H2;"N/A")
```

and Second formula is:

```
=IF(E2="Investigation";OFFSET(H2;-1;0)-H2;"N/A")
```

Basically I want to get as result of the IF function 0 (zero) everytime that the subtraction of the values in column H are negative. But still taking in consideration that sometimes the ouput is N/A (when the words new of investigation are not found).

Thanks a lot for any input.

Comment: Wrap the `TRUE` section of your `IF` in a `MIN` function: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MIN-function-61635d12-920f-4ce2-a70f-96f202dcc152

Comment: Could you give an example? Because i dont think I could use it here.. mainly coz the output must be zero when the result in negative, therefore the smallest number will be the negative .. am I right? Thank you

Comment: Woops, I meant `MAX`. I often get confused which one to use until I write it out :-). See my answer.

Comment: correct! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `MAX` function to limit results to zero or greater. For example, change your first formula to:

```
=IF(E2="New";MAX(OFFSET(H2;-1;0)-H2;0);"N/A")
```

This keeps it to the larger of zero or the subtraction result.

Comment: Woops again. I used a comma instead of semicolon. Fixed now.